# Add salt in password

Tags: php

I use php code to connect my application with localhost. My application register and login actually already success, but now i would like to add salt in my password. So, I follow this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwxAyiAtrbM to implement salt in my application user password, but after i add, the application cannot register user. I dont know why cannot register. Hope get feedback. Below is my php code:

```
<?php 

class DbOperations{

    private $con; 

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }
    public function encrypt($string, $key){
        $string = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
    }
    public funtion decrypt($string, $key){
        $string = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
    public funtion hashword($string, $salt){
        $string = crypt($string, '$P$' .$salt . '$');
    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($user_login, $user_pass,$user_email, $user_registered){
        if($this->isUserExist($user_login,$user_email)){
            return 0; 
        }else{
            $password = hashword($password, $salt);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`,`user_email`,`user_registered`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$user_login,$user_pass,$user_email,$user_registered);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1; 
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }

    public function userLogin($user_login, $user_pass){
        $user_pass = md5($user_pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ? AND user_pass = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$user_login,$user_pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($user_login){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$user_login);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }


    private function isUserExist($user_login, $user_email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ? OR user_email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_login, $user_email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to encrypt and verify passwords

Comment: add salt, why? you realize you're wasting your time with this, if you plan on going live with this. Is this for educational purposes?

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is for client shop app, now is my boss want me connect my application login with wordpress woocommerce, I success connect my application with wordpress, my user information will send to wp-user in wordpress and the password is set as MD5. But when my user register account in wordpress, the password will hash to $P$B, so i cannot login into my app with these password.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I already ask many time in stackoverflow, no one give feedback, I see wordpress, got use salt, so i thought can use salt to implement password

Answer (score 2):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, I would strongly advice you to rewrite your implementation to use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify). These methods are **secure** and very, very easy to use. You do not even need to specify your own salt, because it is more secure to let the algorithm specify one for you!

You use it like this

**Hashing**

```
$hash = password_hash($raw_user_password);
```

**Verifying**

```
$is_correct_password = password_verify($raw_user_password, $hashed_password_from_db);
```

Note that if you use this method you will not be able to run a SQL query on the format `WHERE user_login = ? AND user_pass = ?`. You will have to do `WHERE user_login = ?`, fetch the result, then run the `password_verify` method on the value of `user_pass`. This is much more secure than your current implementation.